# How to avoid await hell in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, puppeteer, chain

I am trying to use puppeteer api and I see that I constantly need to use the await keyword.

e.g.

```
let title = await (await (await page
                .$("#someId"))
                .$x(".."))[0]
                .$eval("span:first-child", el=>el.innerText);
```

If the returned objects where not promises the api could be easily chained like this:

```
let title = page
            .$("#someId")
            .$x("..")[0]
            .$eval("span:first-child", el=>el.innerText);
```

Is there any library that could fix this, e.g. by proxifying the returned objects?

e.g. A possible usage that comes to my mind would be:

```
let title = await awaitProxy(page)
            .$("#someId")
            .$x("..")[0]
            .$eval("span:first-child", el=>el.innerText)
            .awaitProxyValue();
```

Comment: No, the code is async you have to deal with it. At least you don't have to use call backs! It seems half you problem here is that your trying to do a lot on one line of code. If you simply split it up it's much easier to read

Comment: @Liam I have to admin that there is less heat than in callback hell :). But, If I split it up I will need to use a lot of intermediate variables for no reason.

Answer (score 4):

There may be a library that wraps promises and awaits then more gracefully, but normally I mix and match Promises and async/await to make code more readable.
For instance, in your example, it would go somewhat like this:

```
let title = await page.$("#introduction")
  .then(intro => intro.$x(".."))
  .then(results => results[0])
  .then(first => first.$eval("span:first-child", el => el.innerText));
```

That way, `await` is only used to unbox the value once.

Comment: Or just use `const intro = await intro.$x("..");` etc

Comment: @Liam True. You get a few more variables along the way but IMO that makes code more maintainable.